# Passing a full pathname as arguments to a script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I need to write a shell script that gets a full filename PATH, as a command line argument, and displays the file.

Comment: No efforts seen.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
cat "$@"
```

The `"$@"` would be expanded to all the script's command line arguments, individually quoted.

If this is an executable file called `script.sh`, you would use it as

```
./script.sh file
```

to display the contents of `file`. Or even

```
./script.sh file1 file2
```

to view two files after each other.

Though, it would be quicker just to type `cat file` on the command line.  Or `less file` if you want a pager to view the file a screen-full at a time.